# How to follow up after interview when some interviewers did not show?

Tags: professionalism, follow-up

I just completed an interview for an entry level job. Some members of the panel originally scheduled to participate did not show. These people are VP managerial level or above. I know following up with a thank you note, preferably hand written or secondarily through email, is essential as it demonstrates professionalism, interest in the job, and above all appreciation for the interviewers time spent interviewing you.

How can I professionally handle this situation?

Comment: "I know following up with a thank you note, preferably hand written or secondarily through email, is essential". This depends enormously on your industry. My opinion of a candidate has never been changed one way or the other by a thank you note or lack thereof.

Comment: "How van I..." is probably not your question - it is "Who do I address?" Since your description of the people involved is vague, and you also don't mention who else is involved, we can't answer this.

Comment: I'd direct your thank you either to the person who chaired the interview panel, or the contact you've been communicating with when setting the interview up.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have answered your own question. Just follow up and be professional about it.

The thank-you note could include something for those that were not available during your interview. "I know your time is very valuable and I am sorry that I missed you. I hope we get a chance to catch up in the near future" or something of the like. At the very least send an email to those who interviewed you thanking them for their time.

I have been there myself. I went through three round of interviews for an out-of-state position, including a face-to-face. The more reciprocal communication you exchange, the more interested you seem about the position IMHO.

Comment: Good answer but I would regard an interview where multiple interviewers didn't turn up as a -ve signal.

Comment: It's Ok if enough turn up. Interviewers list could be "We need X and Y there. Z would be good. And A, B if they are available which they sometimes are, so they see the candidate instead of having to rely on a report". If X, Y and A are there, that's fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had many thoughts about follow-up strategy but then I came across [an article that went completely against my instincts.](http://tipsnguts.com/should-i-follow-up-after-interview/)

Against what most career sites advise, it says:

> Make your mind to not follow up after the interview - do this before you have even attended the interview - to avoid anxiety.

**Reasons?**
- Deciding to follow up gives you psychological insecurity of not being chosen - and it is great disservice to your self-respect.

- While in some cases it maybe right to ask for a job, asking for the result of an examination / evaluation is akin to accepting that you didn't deserve to know it in the first place.
- If you are good, nothing stops your employer from contacting you. After all, they invited you and had a face-to-face conversation. How can they forget to even inform you? If you were not good, following up only adds insult to injury.

Of-course, a valid exception to this rule is when a recruiter (3rd party) is responsible for communication between you and your prospective employer.

Follow up makes no sense except those cases.